# Installing OpenZeppelin Dependencies in Brownie

Tags: python, brownie, openzeppelin

In my brownie project, I want to install OpenZepplin dependencies. I have included the dependency in the config file, but Brownie is not automatically installing them. What am I doing wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OS6Ff.png)

I tried hitting `brownie compile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed openzepplin dependencies using the brownie pm first?

You can install it using this:

```
brownie pm install OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.0.0
```

Also, have a look at this link here for more info:
https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/package-manager.html

Comment: Thanks. I had not done that.